# Can you pass a directives from a parent component to a child element?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have this component:

```
<styled-input
    [(value)]="myValue"
    validationDirective1
    validationDirective2
    required
    email
></styled-input>
```

Internally:

```
<div>
     <input 
         [value]="value" 
         (input)="valueChanged.emit($event.target.value)"/>
     <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let error of errors">{{ error }}</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

How would I pass the validation down into the `styled-input` component?

Answer (score 0):

Once you declare the directive inside the app module. You can access that directive across whole application. Hence, directly point out directive inside child component (input element).